# missing libnoise.dll prevents program from running

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have made a project and linked the libnoise library to it, it runs fine when I include the files but as soon as I run this bit of code -

```
  noise::module::Perlin myModule;
  double value = myModule.GetValue (14.50, 20.25, 75.75);
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

it throws me this error:

```
the program can't start because libnoise.dll is missing from your computer. Try re installing the program to fix this problem.
```

I already have the .dll in the same folder as the .exe and it should be linked correctly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does libnoise.dll has everything it needs? It may be one of its dependencies to be missing (then it'll fail to load).

Comment: I do believe so, I'm using the liibrary [http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/index.html] I think that is the commonly used library.. I am kinda new to this

Comment: Check out the executable's working directory. It may not be the one it's built in.

Comment: you life saver, you. Post this as an answer so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say you were using Visual Studio. The IDE has the concept of 'working directory', which happens to be the directory the loader starts looking for dynamic libraries your executable might depend on.

Properly setting the WD to the directory in which the executable gets generated is the way to go.